# Are almost sequential spaces sequential?

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is called

$\bullet$ *sequential* if for each non-closed subset $A\subset X$  there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\omega}\subset A$ that converges to a point $a\notin A$;

$\bullet$ *almost sequential* if each point $x\in X$ is contained in a dense sequential subspace of $X$.

> **Question.** Is there an almost sequential regular space $X$ which is not sequential (and moreover, contains a closed countable subspace $F\subset X$ that has no non-trivial convergent sequences)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is a regular non-sequential almost sequential space in ZFC+CH. (See below for a construction using a weaker assumption.)

For $S,T\subseteq \omega$ let $S\subseteq^* T$ denote inclusion modulo finite sets i.e. $S\setminus T$ is finite.
For $f,g:\omega\to\omega$ let $f\leq^* g$ denote dominance modulo finite sets i.e. $f(n)\leq g(n)$ except for finitely many $n.$
Greek letters will denote elements of $\omega_1.$

The construction will make use of an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\omega,$
a cofinal increasing $\omega_1$-sequence $S_\alpha$ in $(\mathcal U,\supseteq^*),$
and a cofinal increasing $\omega_1$ sequence $f_\alpha$ in $(\omega^\omega,\leq^*).$
So $\alpha<\beta$ implies $S_\alpha\supset^* S_\beta,$ and for every set $S$ there is $\alpha$ such that $S\supseteq^* S_\alpha$
or $\omega\setminus S\supseteq^* S_\alpha.$ And $\alpha<\beta$ also implies $f_\alpha\leq^*f_\beta,$ and for every $f$ there is
$\alpha$ such that $f\leq^* f_\alpha.$
I will also require $S_0=\omega.$
These are easy to construct under CH by transfinite induction.
(Specifically, we can take $S_\alpha$ to be a strictly $\subseteq^*$-decreasing subsequence of the sets called $X_\alpha$
in the construction of a Ramsey ultrafilter in Jech's *Set theory* Theorem 7.8 (3rd ed). $f_\alpha(n)$ can be constructed by a very similar argument.)

The ordinals $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ have the ordinal topology.
Let $X$ be the topological space on the set $(\omega\times(\omega+1))\cup\{*\}$ generated by open sets in $\omega\times(\omega+1)$
and the sets $U_{\alpha,n}$ defined for all $\alpha\in\omega_1$ and all integers $n$ by
$$U_{\alpha,n}=\{*\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid x>n\text{ and either }x\in S_\alpha\text{ or }y\leq f_\alpha(x)\}.$$
The sets $U_{\alpha,n}$ are a neighborhood subbase of $\{*\}.$

**$X$ is regular.** It has a subbase of clopen sets.

**$X$ is not sequential.** The subspace $A=\omega\times\{\omega\}$ has $\{*\}$ as a limit point.
This is because any finite intersection $U_{\alpha_1,n_1}\cap \dots\cap U_{\alpha_k,n_k}\cap A$
is just $S_{\max(\alpha_i)}\times\{\omega\}$ minus a finite set, and is therefore non-empty.
Suppose for contradiction that a sequence $(x_n,\omega)$ converges to $*.$ Split $\{x_n\}$ into two infinite sets.
One of these sets, call it $S,$ is not in $\mathcal U.$ There is $\alpha$ such that $\omega\setminus S\supseteq^* S_\alpha.$
The corresponding subsequence therefore lies outside $U_{\alpha,n}$ for sufficiently large $n.$

**$X$ is almost sequential.** Each $x\neq *$ lies in the dense sequential subspace $X\setminus\{*\}.$
The point $*$ lies in the subspace $A=(\omega\times\omega)\cup \{*\}$ which is clearly dense, and it remains to show that it is sequential. The only problem is at $*.$ Accordingly, consider a set $C\subseteq A\setminus\{*\}$ such that $*$ is a limit point of $C,$
and we need to exhibit a sequence converging to $*.$
Define $C_\gamma=\{(x,y)\in C\mid x\in S_\gamma\}.$

First consider the case that $*$ is a limit point of $C_\gamma$ for every $\gamma.$
Let $D=\{x\mid \exists y.(x,y)\in C\}.$
Pick any function $f:\omega\to\omega$ with $(x,f(x))\in C$ for each $x\in D.$
Pick $\alpha$ such that $f\leq^* f_\alpha.$ Take any strictly increasing sequence $x_n$ in $D\cap S_\alpha.$ Consider an arbitrary $U_{\beta,N}.$
We either have $\beta\leq\alpha$ giving $x_n\in S_\beta$ eventually, or $\beta\geq\alpha$ giving $f(x_n)\leq f_\beta(x_n)$ eventually.
This proves that $(x_n,f(x_n))$ converges to $*.$

Now assume that $*$ is not a limit point of $C_\gamma,$ for some $\gamma.$
Take $\gamma$ to be minimal. So $*$ is a limit point of $C_{\beta}$ if and only if $\beta<\gamma.$
Since $0\neq\gamma<\omega_1$ there is a countable sequence $\beta_n$ with $\sup(\beta_n+1)=\gamma.$
For each $n,N$ the set $C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ must intersect the neighborhood $U_{\gamma,N},$
which means there are $(x,y)\in C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ with $x>N$ and $y\leq f_\gamma(x).$
Therefore $C_{\beta_1}\cap\dots\cap C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ (which might be smaller than $C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ at a finite number of $x$-coordinates) contains some $(x_n,y_n)$ with $x_n>N$ and $y_n\leq f_\gamma(x_n).$ We can pick such a choice of $(x_n,y_n)$ for each $n,$ using $N$ to ensure that $x_n$ is strictly increasing.
This construction ensures that for each $\beta<\gamma$ the sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ eventually lies in $C_{\beta},$
and $y_n\leq f_\gamma(x_n)$ for all $n.$ So for each $\beta,N$ the sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ eventually lies in $U_{\beta,N}.$
This proves that $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $*.$

---

If I understand correctly, the above argument relied on $\mathfrak{u}=\mathfrak{d}=\aleph_1.$ I believe this assumption can be weakened to $\mathfrak{d}=\aleph_1,$ which is used for the diagonalization at the end.

The argument is very similar. We still have $f_\alpha$ but no ultrafilter nor $S_\alpha.$ I will assume $f_0(n)=0.$ Pick a bijective function $p:\omega\times\omega\to\omega.$ The base set for $X$ will instead be $(\omega\times\omega\times(\omega+1))\cup\{*\},$ and $U_{\alpha,N}$ will instead be
$$U_{\alpha,N}=\{*\}\cup\{(x,y,z)\mid x>N\text{ and either }y\geq f_\alpha(x) \text{ or }z\leq f_\alpha(p(x,y))\}.$$

This $X$ also has a subbase of clopen sets, and is not sequential because it has a non-sequential closed subspace, the Arens-Fort space $(\omega\times\omega\times\{\omega\})\cup\{*\}.$
As before, $X\setminus\{*\}$ is sequential.
To show that $(\omega\times\omega\times\omega)\cup\{*\}$ is sequential,
consider a set $C\subseteq \omega\times\omega\times\omega$ such that $*$ is a limit point of $C.$ Define $C_\gamma=\{(x,y,z)\in C\mid y\geq f_\gamma(x)\}.$

First consider the case that $*$ is a limit point of $C_\gamma$ for every $\gamma.$
Let $D=\{(x,y)\mid \exists z.(x,y,z)\in C\}.$
Pick any function $f:\omega\to\omega$ with $(x,y,f(p(x,y)))\in C$ for each $(x,y)\in D.$
Pick $\alpha$ such that $f\leq^* f_\alpha.$ Pick a sequence of pairs $(x_n,y_n)\in D$ with $x_n\to\infty$ and $y_n\geq f_\alpha(x_n)$ (these exist because $C_\alpha$ is not bounded in the $x$ direction). Consider an arbitrary $U_{\beta,N}.$
We either have $\beta\leq\alpha$ giving $y_n\geq f_\beta(x_n)$ eventually, or $\beta\geq\alpha$ giving $f(p(x_n,y_n))\leq f_\beta(p(x_n,y_n))$ eventually.
This proves that $(x_n,y_n,f(p(x_n,y_n)))$ converges to $*.$

Now assume that $*$ is not a limit point of $C_\gamma,$ for some $\gamma.$
Take $\gamma$ to be minimal. So $*$ is a limit point of $C_{\beta}$ if and only if $\beta<\gamma.$
Since $0\neq\gamma<\omega_1$ there is a countable sequence $\beta_n$ with $\sup(\beta_n+1)=\gamma.$
For each $n,N$ the set $C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ must intersect the neighborhood $U_{\gamma,N},$
which means there are $(x,y,z)\in C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ with $x>N$ and $z\leq f_\gamma(p(x,y)).$
Therefore $C_{\beta_1}\cap\dots\cap C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ (which might be smaller than $C_{\beta_n}\setminus C_\gamma$ at a finite number of $x$-coordinates) contains some $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ with $x_n>N$ and $z_n\leq f_\gamma(p(x_n,y_n)).$ We can pick such a choice of $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ for each $n,$ using $N$ to ensure that $x_n$ is strictly increasing.
This construction ensures that for each $\beta<\gamma$ the sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ eventually lies in $C_{\beta},$
and $z_n\leq f_\gamma(p(x_n,y_n))$ for all $n.$ So for each $\beta,N$ the sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ eventually lies in $U_{\beta,N}.$
This proves that $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ converges to $*.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your third condition contradicts the second one. In fact, the second is true but the third is not.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: Sorry, I hadn't thought that through. I've now come up with a different construction using CH.

Comment: Thank you for another answer. I have some remarks: (1) it seems that the sequences $(S_\alpha)$ and $(f_\alpha)$ can be constructed under the assumtion $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak c$ (which is weaker than CH and follows from MA, actually it is equivalently to some version of MA); (2) usually by $\kappa^+$ the successor cardinal to $\kappa$ is denoted. So, your $\omega^+$ is a bit misleading; your can write $\omega+1$ or $\bar\omega$ instead.

Comment: And the main problem is with your definition of the topology at $*$: as $\alpha$ icreases so do the sets $U_{n,\alpha}$ but it should be vice-versa. If you replace $\le$ by $\ge$ in the definition of $U_{n,\alpha}$, then you will obtain the standard compact metrizable topology on $(\omega\times\{\omega\})\cup\{*\}$ and this will not allow you to prove that your space is not sequential.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: Thanks for the comments! The sets $U_{n,\alpha}$ are not increasing in $\alpha$ - they just form a subbase of $*.$ The sequence $S_\alpha$ is $\supseteq^*$-increasing i.e. decreasing modulo finite sets. I've fixed the ordinal notation.

Comment: That should be "neighborhood subbase" in the last comment. Also I did spot one $\subseteq^*$ reversed in the "Specifically,.." sentence, fixed now.

Comment: @Dab Thank you for the corrections. Now it indeed works! Now it would be nice to weaken CH to something like $\mathfrak u\le\mathfrak d$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: I think I've weakened the assumption to $\mathfrak{d}=\aleph_1.$

Comment: $2^\kappa$ for uncountable $\kappa$ is a ZFC example of an almost sequential non-sequential space. To see why it's almost sequential, let $x$ be any point in $2^\kappa$ and let $D=\{y \in 2^\kappa: |\{\alpha < \kappa: x(\alpha) \neq y(\alpha) \}| < \aleph_0 \}$. Then $D$ is a sequential (even Fréchet-Urysohn) dense subspace of $2^\kappa$ which contains $x$.

Comment: @SantiSpadaro: oh, wow. That should be an answer so it's more visible

Comment: Ok, I've just added it.

Answer (score 4):

$2^\kappa$ for uncountable $\kappa$ is a ZFC example of an almost sequential non-sequential space.

The easiest way to see why it's not sequential is to note that there is a set $A \subset 2^\kappa$ and a point $p \in \overline{A}$ such that $p$ is not in the closure of any countable subset of $A$. It suffices to take $A=\{x \in 2^\kappa: |x^{-1}(1)| < \aleph_0 \}$ and $p \in 2^\kappa$ to be the function constantly equal to 1.

To see why it's almost sequential, let $x$ be any point in $2^\kappa$ and let $D=\{y \in 2^\kappa: |\{\alpha < \kappa: x(\alpha) \neq y(\alpha) \}| < \aleph_0 \}$. Then $D$ is a sequential (even Fréchet-Urysohn) dense subspace of $2^\kappa$ which contains $x$.

Comment: Thank you! It is so evident!